# CASE Statment and IN() Operator in JOIN Condition

Tags: sql, oracle, join, case

I'm trying to create a join that follows the following logic:

> If our company is the Plaintiff, join to the following role types in
>   the table: Defense Firm, Defense Attorney
>
> If our company is the Defendant, join to the following role types in
>   the table: Plaintiff Firm, Plaintiff Attorney

So far, I have this code written in the join, but it always produces an error for every syntax I've tried:

```
WHERE

TRIAL.TRIAL_ID = OPPOSITION.TRIAL_ID
AND OPPOSITION.ROLE IN

CASE 
WHEN TRIAL.POSITION = 'Plaintiff' 
THEN  ('Defense Firm','Defense Attorney' )
WHEN TRIAL.POSITION = 'Defendant' 
THEN  ('Plaintiff Firm','Plaintiff Attorney')
END
```

We are currently running on Oracle (??)g.

Is this sort of join logic even possible?

EDITS:

- Fixed the Defendant/Plaintiff mixup in the code section
- Not sure what version of Oracle we're on.

Comment: CASE statement should be used in select not in WHERE clause

Comment: @6ton - you can use a case expression in a JOIN or WHERE clause; but you can only compare the single result of that expression with with something else. You can't do what the OP is attempting...

Comment: Just saw some examples - have never seen it used in WHERE clause. Thanks @AlexPoole

Comment: Oracle 13g? When was it released?

Comment: Your requirement description in plain English makes sense. What you wrote in the WHERE clause doesn't make sense. Namely, when TRIAL.POSITION = 'Plaintiff" then OPPOSITION.ROLE should be in ('Defense Firm', 'Defense Attorney'). You wrote 'PLAINTIFF...' instead of 'DEFENSE'. Note that Alex Poole simply copied what you wrote in the query; you will probably need to fix that before you use his solution.

Comment: You can use `select * from v$version` to check the database version. Though it doesn't really matter here.

Comment: Can you show the whole query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AND/OR logic, with appropriate parenthetical grouping, to achieve this (if I'm following what you need), something like:

```
WHERE TRIAL.TRIAL_ID = OPPOSITION.TRIAL_ID
AND (
  (TRIAL.POSITION = 'Plaintiff'
    AND OPPOSITION.ROLE IN ('Defense Firm', 'Defense Attorney')
  OR
  (TRIAL.POSITION = 'Defendant'
    AND OPPOSITION.ROLE IN ('Plaintiff Firm', 'Plaintiff Attorney')
)
```

Although these look like they should be part of an ANSI JOIN clause, rather than a WHERE clause...